# How can I speed up my old computer?

Tags: software-recommendation

I run Ubuntu on an old Dell Dimension 2400 (with only 2d accel.) and it runs really slow when opening up certain programs, like the Ubuntu Software Center.  So I was just wondering if there is any software that can speed it up.  Any response at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some less powerful DE's such as

[**Xubuntu/XFCE**](http://xubuntu.org/)

Xubuntu is lightweight and contains a basic set of applications, Looks similar to `gnome-panel` .To install it

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

[**Lubuntu/LXDE**](http://lubuntu.net/)

Lubuntu is very lightweight and is very basic. Resembles `gnome-panel` . To install it

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/) distro as it has been designed to have a small footprint as far as performance goes.