# How can I get the the Windows installer (Wubi) for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: installation, 11.04, windows, wubi, downloads

I'm looking for the link to have access to Windows installer for Ubuntu 11.10. My computer has trouble running Ubuntu 12.04 so I want to install an older version.

Comment: old release of 11.04 found here http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/

Answer (score 1):

### Downloading, Installing, and Using an Unsupported Release (Wubi)

You can download unsupported releases, including their `wubi.exe` (Windows) installer, from:

- http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

You should not use unsupported releases, though, because they don't get security updates as new security vulnerabilities are discovered and patched. This puts you at risk. You, and anyone else who depends on the security of your computer or the files on it.

If you choose, in spite of the danger, to use an unsupported release, then:

1. To install it with Wubi, you must have the ISO image (also available from there) in the same directory as `wubi.exe` (since it will not automatically download the ISO image in a way that will work). Ideally these should be the only files in the folder at the time.

   See this question for details: [**Why does wubi fail with a 404 error?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233179/why-does-wubi-fail-with-a-404-error)
2. To update the new system so you at least have the security and stability fixes that were released when it was supported, and to install any software on it that was made available in its official repositories, **and if you want to be able to upgrade it to a later release**, you must change the package manager's download server to the `old-releases` server.

   See this question for details:
   [**How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

### A Better Alternative: Use a Lighter-Weight Desktop Environment

If you've found newer versions of Ubuntu don't seem to work well on your aging machine, I recommend you consider running a lightweight [derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives) of Ubuntu such as:

- [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) ([wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu), [TW](https://askubuntu.com/tags/xubuntu/info), [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu)) – [Xfce](http://xfce.org/)-based ([TW](https://askubuntu.com/tags/xfce/info), [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce)), less resource intensive than [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/)/[Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/), *or*
- [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) ([wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu), [TW](https://askubuntu.com/tags/lubuntu/info), [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu)) – [LXDE](http://lxde.org/)-based ([TW](https://askubuntu.com/tags/lxde/info), [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lxde)), [even less resource-intensive](https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lubuntu_vs_Xubuntu), [very lightweight](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#System_Requirements).

Here's some more information about that:

- [What is the difference between the various Ubuntu flavours?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152857/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-ubuntu-flavours)
- [Which is the best Ubuntu Flavor for an old laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50181/which-is-the-best-ubuntu-flavor-for-an-old-laptop)
- [How can I speed up my old computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66566/how-can-i-speed-up-my-old-computer)
- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)
  (no longer expanded, primarily of historical interest)

### Or, Try to Improve Performance

- [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)